# Text features input format for classification algorithms in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-processing, feature-engineering

I'm starting to use the scikit-learn to do some NLP. I've already used some classifiers from NLTK and now I want to try the ones implemented in scikit-learn.

My data is basically sentences, and I extract features from some words of those sentences to do some classification task. Most of my features are nominal: part-of-speech (POS) of the word, word-to-the-left, POS word-to-the-left, word-to-the-right, POS word-to-the-right, syntactic relations path from one word to another, etc.

When I made some experiments using the NLTK classifiers (Decision Tree, Naive Bayes), the feature set was just a dictionary with the corresponding values for the features: the nominal values. Such as: [ {"postag":"noun", "wleft":"house", "path":"VPNPNP",...},.... ]. I just had to pass this to the classifiers and they did their job.

This is part of the code used:

```
def train_classifier(self):
        if self.reader == None:
            raise ValueError("No reader was provided for accessing training instances.")

        # Get the argument candidates
        argcands = self.get_argcands(self.reader)

        # Extract the necessary features from the argument candidates
        training_argcands = []
        for argcand in argcands:
            if argcand["info"]["label"] == "NULL":
                training_argcands.append( (self.extract_features(argcand), "NULL") )
            else:
                training_argcands.append( (self.extract_features(argcand), "ARG") )

        # Train the appropriate supervised model
        self.classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier.train(training_argcands)

        return
```

Here's an example of one of the feature sets extracted:

```
[({'phrase': u'np', 'punct_right': 'NULL', 'phrase_left-sibling': 'NULL', 'subcat': 'fcl=np np vp np pu', 'pred_lemma': u'revelar', 'phrase_right-sibling': u'np', 'partial_path': 'vp fcl', 'first_word-postag': 'Bras\xc3\xadlia PROP', 'last_word-postag': 'Bras\xc3\xadlia PROP', 'phrase_parent': u'fcl', 'pred_context_right': u'um', 'pred_form': u'revela', 'punct_left': 'NULL', 'path': 'vp\xc2\xa1fcl!np', 'position': 0, 'pred_context_left_postag': u'ADV', 'voice': 0, 'pred_context_right_postag': u'ART', 'pred_context_left': u'hoje'}, 'NULL')]
```

As I mentioned before, most of the features are nominal (a string value).

Now, I want try out the classifiers in the scikit-learn package. As I understand, this type of feature sets are not acceptable for the algorithms implemented in sklearn, since all feature values must be numeric, and they have to be in an array or matrix. Therefore, I transformed the "original" feature sets using the DictVectorizer class. However, when I pass this transformed vectors, I get the following errors:

```
# With DecisionTreeClass
Traceback (most recent call last): 
.....
self.classifier.fit(train_argcands_feats,new_train_argcands_target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py", line 458, in fit
    X = np.asarray(X, dtype=DTYPE, order='F')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number


# With GaussianNB

Traceback (most recent call last):
....
self.classifier.fit(train_argcands_feats,new_train_argcands_target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 156, in fit
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I get these errors when I just use DictVectorizer(). However, if I use DictVectorizer(sparse=False), I get the errors even before the code gets to the training part:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
train_argcands_feats = self.feat_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_argcands_feats)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 123, in fit_transform
    return self.transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 212, in transform
    Xa = np.zeros((len(X), len(vocab)), dtype=dtype)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Because of this error, it's obvious that a sparse representation has to be used.

So the question is: how do I transform my nominal features so as to use the classification algorithms provided by scikit-learn?

Thanks in advance for all the help you could give me.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by an answer below, I tried to use the NLTK wrapper for scikit-learn. I just changed the code line that creates the classifier:

```
self.classifier = SklearnClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
```

Then, when I call the "train" method I get the following:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 100, in train
    X = self._convert(featuresets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 109, in _convert
    return self._featuresets_to_coo(featuresets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.py", line 126, in _featuresets_to_coo
    values.append(self._dtype(v))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: np
```

So, apparently, the wrapper can't create the sparse matrix because the features are nominal.  Then, I'm back to the original problem.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that shows what you are trying to do? Might make it easier for people to help you find the error...

Comment: @JeffTratner Done! If there's anything else you think I should provide , just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ValueError: array is too big.` is quite explicit: you cannot allocate a dense array datastructure of (n_samples, n_features) in memory. It's useless (and impossible in your case) to store that many zeros in a contiguous chunk of memory. Use a sparse datastructure as in the [DictVectorizer documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) instead.

Also if you prefer the NLTK API you can use its scikit-learn integration instead of using scikit-learn `DictVectorizer`:

http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/scikitlearn.html

Have a look at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes! I understood that I had to use a sparse representation. That's why my first attempt was with a DictVectorizer with the default parameters (creates an sparse matrix). However, it threw the first error indicated.

Comment: Alright I understand better but it's hard to follow with just stack traces: it's better to include the complete script to understand what's happening.

So in any case: DecisionTree in sklearn do not support high dim sparse feature. GaussianNB is tailored for continuously. 

For high dim sparse features such as NLP windowing features or TF-IDF doc features it's usually better to use a linear model or a multinomial or bernoulli naive bayesian model. Have a look at this example for instance: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html

Comment: I agree that the error messages are not clear though. The DecisionTree and GaussianNB error messages should explicitly state that sparse data is not supported. Please feel free 2 open 2 github issues to track this.

Comment: I've updated the post with the main code section that causes the problem, as well as an example of a feature set used in the program. Hope that helps. I don't think it's necessary to include the code that extracts each feature.

Comment: Forgot to end that sentence:  GaussianNB is tailored for continuously variables hence not good for indicator variables typically used in NLP (also it does not accept scipy sparse matrices as input).

Comment: Unfortunately, the NLTK wrapper isn't as sophisticated as `DictVectorizer` in handling string-valued features.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the NLTK wrapper for scikit-learn is that it actually wants dicts mapping feature names to numeric values, so that's not going to solve the problem in this case. The `DictVectorizer` is scikit-learn is more sophisticated, in that it does a "one-of-K" coding when it encounters string feature values; here's how you can use it:

```
>>> data = [({'first_word-postag': 'Bras\xc3\xadlia PROP',
   'last_word-postag': 'Bras\xc3\xadlia PROP',
   'partial_path': 'vp fcl',
   'path': 'vp\xc2\xa1fcl!np',
   'phrase': u'np',
   'phrase_left-sibling': 'NULL',
   'phrase_parent': u'fcl',
   'phrase_right-sibling': u'np',
   'position': 0,
   'pred_context_left': u'hoje',
   'pred_context_left_postag': u'ADV',
   'pred_context_right': u'um',
   'pred_context_right_postag': u'ART',
   'pred_form': u'revela',
   'pred_lemma': u'revelar',
   'punct_left': 'NULL',
   'punct_right': 'NULL',
   'subcat': 'fcl=np np vp np pu',
   'voice': 0},
  'NULL')]
```

Break this list into two lists, one containing samples, the other the corresponding labels:

```
>>> samples, labels = zip(*data)
```

Pass the samples to `DictVectorizer.fit` (you can optionally pass the labels as well in a separate argument, but they will be ignored):

```
>>> v = DictVectorizer()
>>> X = v.fit_transform(samples)
>>> X
<1x19 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 19 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

You should then be able to pass `X` to a scikit-learn classifier that accepts sparse input. `GaussianNB` does *not* do that, as @ogrisel already pointed out. For NLP tasks, you'll want to use `MultinomialNB` or `BernoulliNB`, since those are designed specifically for discrete data.

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I ended up doing. But since the conversation with @ogrisel was the one who led to that solution, I marked his answer as the one which solved the problem. Anyway, thank you too!